# For loop to copy paste a folder and rename it using incrementation

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd, command-line, command-prompt

I'm trying to make a for loop to copy a folder "**Profile 1** (and of course all the files inside it) and paste it in the same directory but instead of naming it "**¨Profile 1 - Copy**" I want to name them **Profile 2 Profile 3 Profile 4 ... Profile 50**.
Since I'm still a beginner in the Batch language here what I've done:

```
for /L %n in (2,1,100) do
rem copy and paste 
@echo %n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```batch-file
@echo off
setlocal 
for /L %%n in (2,1,50) do (
 rem copy and paste 
 echo %n
 xcopy /s/e "Profile 1\*" "Profile %%n\" >nul
)
```